# Data Lake Analytics - create credentials in Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, azure, visual-studio-2015, credentials, azure-data-lake

I would like to develop and test U-SQL script using Visual Studio 2015.
I ran into a a problem, because Visual Studio does not allow create credentials in Server Explorer in Local account.

I try to do following:

[image]

Bu I got and error:

```
[Job Error]
E_CSC_USER_CREDENTIALSECRETNOTFOUND: Cannot find secret information for credential 'master.testCred'.
Description:
There is no secret associated with the specified database, identity and user name.
Resolution:
Please create a secret for the specied database, identity and user name.
==========  Local execution failure ==========
```

I was successful to create credentials using [powershell script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/resourcemanager/azurerm.datalakeanalytics/v2.3.0/new-azurermdatalakeanalyticscatalogcredential) in remote ADLA account, but I cannot test the query locally if I cannot create the credentials locally, because I would like to connect into Azure SQL Database as the data source. Is it possible to create credentials using Powershell script locally? If so, how? How can I specify that I would like to use local account?

Without this is the local environment unusable in Visual Studio.

Thank you.

Peter

Comment: if you want to test USQL locally, i would suggest you move the data locally, too, or else things might slow down quite a bit. You could use the Data Copy wizard in Azure Data Factory to move the data into a local version of SQL, or you could export the SQL Azure database to a backup file and restore it locally.

Comment: @MichaelLudwig Could you pelase detailed describe how to connect to local SQL server? It does not make sense for me, I need credentials as well. Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think federated queries are supported in local scenarios (yet). I forwarded your post to the tools team.

**UPDATE:** Apparently this capability used to work but for some reason stopped working in the local run environment. We are currently looking into fixing the regression and re-enabling it.

Comment: Thank you, it helps for test

Answer (score 0):

Local federated query was broken due to language changes that removed "CREDENTIAL" DDLs.   We have fixed it and that should appear in the new iteration of U-SQL SDK.

Comment: This are a great news! Thank you.